# always display submenu in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-navigation

Is there a plug in or a block of code I can add in order to always display submenu?

[image]

The only time I can see the submenu that has a red border around it is when I click the menu item "SHOP", I would like the submenu that has a red border to be visible on any pageall the time

Answer (score 1):

You could do this at the theme layer by editing page.tpl.php and printing $secondary_links.

You might also just prefer to use the Menu Block module, which has some pretty handy config options: http://drupal.org/project/menu_block

Comment: I have installed the module, the only thing with the template that is being used is that the menu is hard codded into the page.tpl.php and it is not a block. Any idea what php code I would use to hard code it into page.tpl.php? I have never used Drupal before, just trying to do a friend a favor. Thanks in advance!